# Google GeoChart onclick setCell not working

Tags: javascript, html, google-maps, google-visualization

I'm having difficulty highlighting countries with the Google GeoCharts API and a checkbox's `onclick`.

My displaymarkers function should use the `setCell` function by passing the input value as the `DataTable`'s row index.

However passing the `check.value` to `setCell` doesn't seem to work. If I simply put `data.setCell(1, 1, 1);` it works perfectly.

How should I go about doing this short of making a lot of if statements?

Javascript:

```
var data;
var chart;
var options;

function drawRegionsMap() {
    data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
        ['Country', 'Popularity'],
        ['United States', 1],
        ['RU', 1]
    ]);

    options = {legend: 'none'};

    chart = new google.visualization.GeoChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
    chart.draw(data, options);
};

function displaymarkers(check) {
    // Checkbox has been checked
    if (check.checked) {
        data.setCell(check.value, 1, 1);
    } else { // Checkbox has been unchecked
        data.setCell(check.value, 1, 0);
    }

    chart.draw(data, options);
}
```

HTML:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="us" onclick="displaymarkers(this)" value="0" checked="checked" />US
<input type="checkbox" name="russia" onclick="displaymarkers(this)" value="1" checked="checked" />Russia
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`check.value` returns a string. `parseInt(check.value)` works.